# datagridview не существует в текущем контексте c#

Tags: c#, winforms, классы, datagridview

Есть загрузка формы

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Teams team1 = new Teams("Teamname", "TrainerName", "Country");
            team1.DisplayInfo();
        }
```

В файле класса Teams есть метод DisplayInfo

```
public void DisplayInfo()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Team Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Trainer", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            table.Rows.Add(TeamName, TeamTrainer, TeamCountry);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
```

Выдает ошибку datagridview1 не существует в текущем контексте. Можно ли как-то добавить использование datagridview в другие файлы кроме Form.cs, если да то как? Не нашел толком никакого ответа. Или нужно по-другому описать метод DisplayInfo()? Подскажите как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ №1:

Мы создаём отдельный класс, где будет храниться DataGridView, так мы обходим ограничение элементов форм (Приватность) и можем работать с элементом из любого класса, но тогда нужно изменять файл дизайнера Form1, чтобы в форме было видно dataGridView1.

File Form1.cs

```
using static DataTables;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Teams team1 = new Teams("Teamname", "TrainerName", "Country");
    team1.DisplayInfo();
}
```

File Teams.cs

```
using static DataTables;
public void DisplayInfo()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Team Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Trainer", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(TeamName, TeamTrainer, TeamCountry);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

File DataTables.cs

```
public static class DataTables
{
   public static DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
}
```

Способ №2:

Теперь DisplayInfo() возвращает DataTable.

File Form1.cs

```
using static Wrapper;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Teams team1 = new Teams("Teamname", "TrainerName", "Country");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = team1.DisplayInfo();
}
```

File Teams.cs

```
using static Wrapper;
public DataTable DisplayInfo()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Team Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Trainer", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(TeamName, TeamTrainer, TeamCountry);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: В первом способе добавил в файле Teams.c в последней строке        
DataTables.dataGridView1.DataSource = table; и программа запустилась, но в форму ничего не вывело. Также Компилятор пишет ошибку на using static Wrapper; я его закоментировал. Во втором способе опять ошибка на using static Wrapper; и в методе public DataTable DisplayInfo() выходит ошибка "не все пути к коду возвращают значение"

Comment: Лучше используйте второй способ, если всё же первый, то Wrapper замените на DataTables

Comment: Во втором способе возникает ошибка не все пути к коду возвращают значение.

Comment: А в первом способе все равно почему-то возникает ошибка на using static DataTables;

Comment: @Алексей, ох да, исправил, извините за неудобства...

Comment: Во  втором ошибка с вашей стороны, возможно вы указали путь к классу не полностью? Попробуйте решить с помощью quickFix от VS (Если вы работаете в этой среде)  бинд: Cntr + ,